# How to fix / refresh start menu in Windows 10? How to add / remove / edit items in bulk?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I have my Start Menu completely damaged after upgrading to Windows 10. Some items are absent another ones are wrong or unneeded.

You can search my other questions for proofs if you don't believe.

The question is how to add my needed items to start menu in bulk? I am not interested in by-one solutions, like reinstalling programs (imagine you yourself reinstall dozens of programs just to put them into menu).

Suppose I have `StartMenu` folder somewhere in the disk, full of subfolders and `LNK` files. Now, how to remove ALL current items from my Main Menu and put all  links and submenus from `StartMenu` folder into my Main Menu?

Comment: What do you mean by parasitic version, what happens when you open it?

Comment: Some reduced read-only version of OneNote opens, which does not show my notebooks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*(Edit: This answer mostly relates to Windows 10 prior to Version 1511.)*

The Windows 10 Start menu has several known bugs.
You might have run against the particularly noxious bug
[limiting the total number of entries to 512](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_desktop/some-win32-apps-missing-from-start-menu-all/b41f1f57-5af3-468d-896f-bd283aa6cfdf?page=26).
That's not 512 applications, by the way - that's 512 items in total, including apps, folders, files and shortcuts.
*(EDIT: starting with Version 1511 Microsoft has significantly increased this limit.)*

The best solution, in my opinion, is not to fight against these bugs,
since you really have no other option than wait for a fix from Microsoft.
Instead, until Microsoft gets its act together, replace its Start menu
with a third-party one. The top contenders are :

- The free [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) (recommended)
  *Note : This has been superseded by*
  [*Open-Shell-Menu*](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu),
- [Start10](https://www.stardock.com/products/start10/) ($4.99)
  *Note : This has been superseded by
  [Start11](https://www.stardock.com/products/start11/).*

Otherwise, here is a list of workarounds for the Microsoft one :

1. Rebuild the search index by going to Control Panel / Indexing Options / Advanced and using the Rebuild button.
2. [Reset the Start menu layout](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-reset-the-start-menu-layout-in-windows-10/) by opening an elevated command prompt,
   exit Explorer, delete the Start menu database at
   `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\appsFolder.menu.itemdata-ms`
   and run Explorer again. *(EDIT: this file no longer exists in newer versions of Windows 10.)*
3. Ensure your Windows 10 Start Menu does not exceed 512 items by reducing the
   number of indexed locations
4. [Reinstall all applications](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/how-fix-start-menu-in-windows-10-3623893/), by entering in Powershell as Administrator
   `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`
5. Try a new user account, since your profile might be damaged

Even if one of the workarounds works for you, the bug can hit again at any time.
The only lasting solution is to use a more stable Start menu replacement.

Comment: If I use `Start10`, will I be able to restore my apps in bulk?

Comment: Nevermind! `Classic Shell` seemed perfect! :)

Comment: @harrymc - It does not really change your answer but starting with Version 1511 Microsoft increased the limited on the number of items significantly.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks - I have added your remark in the text.

Comment: There's also Open-Shell which is an open source successor of Classic Shell

Comment: @YakovL: Thanks - I have added this to my answer,

Answer (score 4):

To "refresh" the Start Menu, follow these steps:

1. Open the "Run command" window by pressing WIN+R.
   (i.e. hold down the Windows key and then press R.)
2. Type "cmd" at the prompt, and press Enter.
3. Wait for the command prompt to open.
   (It will be a flashing cursor block.)
4. At the command prompt, type this:
   `taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F`
   You should notice these all vanish: Start Menu, Taskbar, any open File Explorer windows.
5. Type this at the command prompt:
   `explorer.exe`
   Now those components should all load back in.
6. Close the command prompt and try the Start Menu. Hopefully it should have refreshed.

Comment: Make sure to get the command prompt and not just paste the taskkill into Run, since Win+R won't work afterwards. I regained my command prompt by right-clicking a tab in Notepad++.

Comment: @Noumenon Also, the infamous Ctrl+Alt+Del allows you to launch Task Manager, in which you'l find a "Run Mew Task" menu option...

Comment: This just closes explorer, same result as restarting the PC which is way easier for average people. Ctrl+Shift+Right-click open Taskbar area has Exit Explorer

Answer (score 0):

You can find 'start menu' under: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

You can also set default 'Apps' at: Settings -> System -> 'Default apps'

Comment: Yes, I can finde something in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`, but the content of this folder is not correspond with the content of visually presented items. For example, this folder contains my actual OneNote link, which is not presented when I am entering my search

Answer (score 0):

You could uninstall the application as a whole.
You wont be able to do so in the app manager, it's grayed out.

You need to open a powershell as admin and type this in

```
Remove-AppxPackage Microsoft.Office.OneNote_17.6027.10021.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

if this one doesn't work try this

```
Remove-AppxPackage Microsoft.Office.OneNote_17.4027.10061.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```